# How to deserialize polymorphic LinkedList with Jackson JSON and JAVA?

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson, deserialization

I´m having some problems when i try to deserializing a Java class.
My classes are :

```
Abstract Class A {
Long ID
String name 
...
}
Class B extends A{ 
String Type
String Value
}
Class C extends A{
List<A> typedList;
}
```

And my Serialization/Deseralization Methods:

```
public String serialize(T object) {
        String returnValue = "";

        try {
            returnValue = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

public List<T> unserialize(String data, Class<?> clazz) {
        List<T> returnValue = new LinkedList<T>();
        //JavaType topMost = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(MyWrapper.class, ActualClassRuntime.class); 
        try {

            returnValue = (List<T>) mapper.readValue(data,clazz);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

The list inside the C class contain B and C elements. Serialization is done without problems but when i tried to deserialize C , Jackson can´t rebuild my typedList correctly.
It uses LinkedHashMap instead of LinkedList and don´t use the correct types. 
Any ideias how to solve this ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @alfasin this has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you expect to get a List, you must pass a List type: here you are giving type of `clazz` but expect type of `List<T>`. This won't work, even if `clazz` is of type `List`.
So you need to pass proper type. But for List (and Map) types, you further need to specify contents type: and type variable does not do. What works is something like:

```
List<MyType> list = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, new TypeReference<List<MyType>>() { });
```

where `TypeReference` must be used due to Java type erasure.

You can also construct structured types from components dynamically, if they are passed as arguments:

```
Class<?> elem = ...;
List<?> list = mapper.readValue(jsonSource,
  mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class, elem);
```

The reason you get `LinkedHashMap` is just because of missing type information: if JSON Object is encountered, and requested type is `java.lang.Object` (as would be the case if you just passed type `List.class` to bind to), this is the type that would be used.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm =).