# ClassCastException when convert json to list of objects

Tags: java, json

I am using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html) library to process json data.

I have created a **generic** function to convert json string to a model class object:

```
public <T> T parseJsonToObject(String jsonStr, Class<T> clazz) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

     return null; 
}
```

I have a Person class:

```
public class Person{
   @JsonProperty("first_name")
   private String firstName;

   @JsonProperty("last_name")
   private String lastName;
   //Getter & Setters ...
}
```

I got server response which is a List of persons:

```
[{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith"},{"first_name":"Kate","last_name":"Green"}]
```

My `String jsonPersonsStr` holds the above json string.

Now I try to use my function to directly convert the json string to a List of Person:

```
List<Person> persons = parseJsonToObject(jsonPersonsStr, ArrayList.class);
```

But I got Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.my.models.Person
```

How to modify my generic function to get rid of this Exception?

Comment: Will probably have to use a `TypeReference`. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9502822/1174467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can probably do is to support one generic method for `Collection` types, and possibly others for non-`Collection` types.

Here's a working version of the generic `Collection` method:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory;

//...

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "rawtypes" })
public static <E, T extends Collection> T parseJsonToObject(String jsonStr, Class<T> collectionType, Class<E> elementType) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, TypeFactory.collectionType(collectionType, elementType));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Then you would call this like:

```
List<Person> persons = parseJsonToObject(s, ArrayList.class, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
listOfObjects = mapper.readValue(connection.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<List<Person>>(){});
```

the problem here is due to Java's implementation on generics (List in this case)

Comment: Yes, I know this way will solve the problem, but as I said that function is a generic function, it is not only for this list of persons json string. I am seeking for a way to keep the function as generic as possible & could get my problem solved.

Comment: Then you're gonna have a problem because if your clazz is a List<Something> it won't work

Comment: You may try to return the new TypeReference<clazz>(){} instead of clazz, however I am not sure if this will work...

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JSON. Everything works fing if I try it with your Informations?

Try this static exsample. I define my own `PersonList` (need no content)

```
public class JsonDeserializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonString = "[{\"first_name\":\"John\",\"last_name\":\"Smith\"},{\"first_name\":\"Kate\",\"last_name\":\"Green\"}]";
        List<Person> persons = parseJsonToObject(jsonString, PersonList.class);
        System.out.println("Persons: " + persons);
        for (Person person : persons) {
            System.out.println("Person " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
        }
    }

    public static class PersonList extends ArrayList<Person> {
    } 

    public static <T> T parseJsonToObject(String jsonStr, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(jsonStr, clazz);        
    }

    public static class Person {

        @JsonProperty("first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @JsonProperty("last_name")
        private String lastName;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" + "firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I use maven an this json lib

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**:

Works also with Codehaus's jackson (1.7.3)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Well, I am not able to use this version Jackson, since my Jackson is actually a buildin feature of another 3rd party library.

Comment: This is a poor test. The problem is not casting to `List`, the problem is casting the elements in the list to `Person`.

Comment: This test returns a List with objects of `Person` (`List<Person>`). Cannot see why this is a poor test.

Comment: It's probably returning a `List<Map>`. Try getting one of the elements and casting it to a `Person`. That's where the exception occurs.

Comment: @superEb Ok, you are right - sorry. I will have a look on it.

Comment: @superEB I change a few things. Now it seems to work. Will you have a look? Thanks

Comment: That will probably work, but it's not the most generic solution.